# Javascript array splice doesn't work with JQuery click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

in for loops, array.splice doesn't work
the array doesn't change

I changed some position, confirm it doesn't work in chrome.

```
var menu =['#men','#wmen','#ftwear','#accsries','#chldren','#dscver']

for( var i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){ 
 $(menu[i]).click(function(){
   menu.splice(i, 1);
   console.log(menu) 
   menu.forEach(function(list){
     $(list+' ul').slideUp(300)
     $(list).removeClass('bold') 
   })
   menu.splice(i, 0, menu[i]);
  console.log(menu) 
 })
 }
```

I hope the for Loops work with array.splice

Comment: Idk why Barmar marked this as a duplicate when the referenced post (while related) does not qualify as an answer for this post. To help you out @Siu keep in mind that the `$(elem).click()` method only registers a listener to your button. By the time the user clicks that button the `i` variable in your for loop will always be 6 (the length of your array). Thus the last element will always be spliced off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind the value of `i` to the function inside the click - since it is called asynchronously. Try using `let` instead of `var` inside the `for` statement:

```
var menu =['#men','#wmen','#ftwear','#accsries','#chldren','#dscver']

for( let i = 0; i < menu.length; i++){ 
 $(menu[i]).click(function(){
   menu.splice(i, 1);
   console.log(menu) 
   menu.forEach(function(list){
     $(list+' ul').slideUp(300)
     $(list).removeClass('bold') 
   })
   menu.splice(i, 0, menu[i]);
  console.log(menu) 
 })
 }
```